# String all characters in grok

Tags: parsing, logstash, grok

How can I parse the field jsession in the following log line?

```
2015-11-02 11:28:02,838 [TF701_0101] [124] [10.126.132.10] [JWFhW36DfTCZYpGgzF3QlDwN8j2cDznrKSBvz8hQw0lkTdknr67Y!1315365112!-629296615; path=/]
```

This is the filter I have currently

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:tiempo} \[%{WORD:instancia}\] \[%{NUMBER:numerico}\] \[%{IP:cliente}\] \[%{WORD:jsession}\]"}
    }
    date {
        match => [ "tiempo" , "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more info? What do you get with this code? What's not working?

Answer (score 1):

Your grok pattern is almost good. If you use `GREEDYDATA` for your `jsession` field instead of `WORD` you'll get what you need:

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:tiempo} \[%{WORD:instancia}\] \[%{NUMBER:numerico}\] \[%{IP:cliente}\] \[%{GREEDYDATA:jsession}\]"}
    }
    date {
        match => [ "tiempo" , "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
    }
}
```

Running this filter with your sample log line would yield the following output:

```
{
       "message" => "2015-11-02 11:28:02,838 [TF701_0101] [124] [10.126.132.10] [JWFhW36DfTCZYpGgzF3QlDwN8j2cDznrKSBvz8hQw0lkTdknr67Y!1315365112!-629296615; path=/]",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-11-02T10:28:02.838Z",
          "host" => "iMac.local",
        "tiempo" => "2015-11-02 11:28:02,838",
     "instancia" => "TF701_0101",
      "numerico" => "124",
       "cliente" => "10.126.132.10",
      "jsession" => "JWFhW36DfTCZYpGgzF3QlDwN8j2cDznrKSBvz8hQw0lkTdknr67Y!1315365112!-629296615; path=/"
}
```